# Select 3 items from list, print different messages based on selection order

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I want to see if I can find a way to have the system work the same way when it runs, but condense it, as if I don't I will be constantly writing a lot of code that I believe I could just write in a more simple and condensed way.

Is there a way to simplify and condense this code?

```
import random
aList = ["1", "2", "3"]
bList = random.choice(aList)
print(bList)
if bList == "1": # prints 1
    aList.pop(0)
    cList1 = random.choice(aList)
    print("This thing happened again")
    print(cList1)
    if cList1 == "2": # prints 2 in 1
        aList.pop(0)
        dList1 = random.choice(aList)
        print("This happened.")
        print(dList1)
    if cList1 == "3": # prints 3 in 1
        aList.pop(1)
        dList2 = random.choice(aList)
        print("That happened.")
        print(dList2)
else:
    pass
if bList == "2":
    aList.pop(1)
    cList2 = random.choice(aList)
    print("Text")
    print(cList2)
    if cList2 == "1": # prints 1 in 2 
        aList.pop(0)
        dList3 = random.choice(aList)
        print("Random text")
        print(dList3)
    if cList2 == "3": # prints 3 in 2
        aList.pop(1)
        dList4 = random.choice(aList)
        print("More Random Text")
        print(dList4)
else:
    pass
if bList == "3":
    aList.pop(2)
    cList3 = random.choice(aList)
    print("Here is a random text line")
    print(cList3)
    if cList3 == "1": # prints 1 in 3 
        aList.pop(0)
        dList5 = random.choice(aList)
        print("Here is another random text line")
        print(dList5)
    if cList3 == "2": # prints 2 in 3
        aList.pop(1)
        dList6 = random.choice(aList)
        print("Once again, This")
        print(dList6)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.  Your title is a little too broad and applicable to everything on this site.  The standard is to have the title describe what your code is trying to do.  For that matter, what is your code trying to do?

Comment: (`I want to see if I can [write concise code]`) does that mean you want hints rather than be spoon-fed examples?

Comment: The code seems to be contrived and full of placeholders. So it seems hypothetical to me. As usual, "what are you actually doing? because this definitely isn't it."

Comment: (If this *did* occur in a "real" project, but the code is not written yet (it does *not* need to be *finished*): Where you "see" something untoward, hide it with a suitable abstraction. When it "works" and you still have issues with the way it is coded you are welcome to present [actual code from a project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Answer (score 5):

## PEP 8

The [Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/) enumerates a number of rules you should follow.

Of particular note: variables should be in `snake_case`, not `mixedCase`.  Therefore, `aList` should be `a_list`.

## Misleading names

None of `bList`, `cList1`, `cList2`, `cList3`, `dList1`, `dList2`, `dList3`, `dList4`, `dList5`, `dList6` are actually lists.  They should not be named as if they were as list.

## If-chain

```py
if bList == "1":
    ...
else:
    pass
if bList == "2":
    ...
else:
    pass
if bList == "2":
    ...
else:
    pass
```

implies that it is possible for `bList` to change value so it can match one of the later choices.  It does not change values, so the choices are exclusive.

`else: pass` is unnecessary.  If nothing is executed in the else clause, omit it.

Thus, this could be improved as:

```py
if bList == "1":
    ...
elif bList == "2":
    ...
elif bList == "2":
    ...
```

## Select and remove element

The `.pop()` function returns the element it removes.  It looks like you want to remove a random element.  So, that is what you should actually code.

```py
bList = aList.pop(random.randrange(len(aList)))
```

The `len(aList)` determines the length of `aList`, which is 3.  `random.randrange(3)` generates a random integer in the range `0 <= x < 3` ... as in 0, 1 or 2.  `aList.pop(x)` removes that randomly selected element from the `aList` and returns it.

This eliminates the need for

```py
if bList == "1":
    aList.pop(0)
...
if bList == "2":
    aList.pop(1)
...
if bList == "3":
    aList.pop(2)
...
```

because the element is retrieve and popped in the same operation.

## Updated code

Applying the above changes, we get:

```py
import random

a_list = ["1", "2", "3"]

b = a_list.pop(random.randrange(len(a_list)))
c = a_list.pop(random.randrange(len(a_list)))
d = a_list.pop(random.randrange(len(a_list)))
print(b)
if b == "1":
    print("This thing happened again")
    print(c)
    if c == "2":
        print("This happened.")
    elif c == "3":
        print("That happened.")
elif b == "2":
    print("Text")
    print(c)
    if c == "1":
        print("Random text")
    elif c == "3":
        print("More Random Text")
elif b == "3":
    print("Here is a random text line")
    print(c)
    if c == "1":
        print("Here is another random text line")
    elif c == "2":
        print("Once again, This")
print(d)
```

... which is a little simpler, but is still quite verbose.

## Further Condensed

The structure of the code is take 3 samples without replacement, print out the first value, a message depending on the first value, the second value, a message depending on the first two values, and then the third value.  We can code exactly that:

```py
import random

messages = {"1": "This thing happened again",
            ("1", "2"): "This happened.",
            ("1", "3"): "That happened.",
            "2": "Text",
            ("2", "1"): "Random text",
            ("2", "3"): "More Random Text",
            "3": "Here is a random text line",
            ("3", "1"): "Here is another random text line",
            ("3", "2"): "Once again, This"}
            
a_list = ["1", "2", "3"]
b, c, d = random.sample(a_list, 3)
print(b, messages[b], c, messages[b, c], d, sep="\n")
```